# nginx, questions about $request_method and uri

Tags: nginx, uri

i have the this request:
`request: "PROPFIND / HTTP/1.1", host:`
However, the uri / path should be updated, should look like this.
`request: "PROPFIND /dav HTTP/1.1", host:`
How do i achieve this with something similar ?

```
location = / {
if ($request_method = "PROPFIND") { ???? }
}
```

it is important that the request_method is passed along and only the uri is modified.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you looking for an internal rewrite from `/` to `/dav`  and `/dav/` matches another location?

Comment: yes @Timo Stark, exactly, nginx works as a proxy here.<br/>
I already have this construct: <br/>
``` location = / { if ( $http_user_agent ~ ^DavClnt ) { return 302 /dav/$is_args$args; } if ($request_method = "OPTIONS") { return 302 /dav/; } if ($request_method = "PROPFIND") { ??????? } deny all; } location ^~ /dav { proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:20443; } ```

Comment: The solution was to use `return 307` instead of `return 302`. With `307` the `request_method` is passed through.